# How to show that $\frac{\sinh(b)}{\sinh(a)} \leq \frac{b}{a}$ for $a\geq b>0$.

Tags: integration, inequality, hyperbolic-functions

I want to prove that
$\frac{\sinh(b)}{\sinh(a)} \leq \frac{b}{a}$ where $a\geq b>0$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.
I have tried to set $a = bx$ for $x\geq 1$ but did not manage to show that the inequality holds. Also, I did not manage to prove it via the identity $\frac{\sinh(b)}{\sinh(a)} = \frac{\sinh(b)}{\int_{0}^{a} \cosh(x) dx} = \frac{\sinh(b)}{\int_{0}^{b} \cosh(x) dx + \int_{b}^{a} \cosh(x) dx}$.

Comment: Just show that $f(x)=\frac{\sinh x}{x}$ is monotonically increasing for $x>0$. Then $f(b) \leq f(a)$, which is equivalent to the statement after a re-arrangement.

Comment: I'm almost sad how easy that was. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what @Gary suggested is a consequence of $\sinh$ being *convex.*

Comment: @Gary's $f$ is [a named function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhc_function) worth knowing about.